# How to fill between the lines in a pandas/matplotlib time series plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a data frame which is indexed by DataTime in pandas.

I have data about a car with the Inside temperature, Lowest inside temperature, Highest temperature and the same three features for the Outside temperature.

Thus I plot all 6 features like so as a time series, and have tried to use plt.fill_between like so :

```
car_df[['insideTemp','insideTempLow','insideTempHigh','outsideTemp','outsideTempLow','outsideTempHigh']].plot()
plt.fill_between(car_df['insideTemp'], car_df['insideTempLow'],car_df['insideTempHigh'], data=car_df)
plt.fill_between(car_df['outsideTemp'], car_df['outsideTempLow'],car_df['outsideTempHigh'], data=car_df)
plt.show()
```

I get 6 lines as desired, however nothing seems to get filled (thus not separating the two categories of indoor and outdoor).

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your xaxis? the first argument in fill_between should be your x-array. The question would be clearer if you could post a copy of your actual image.

Answer (score 1):

You passed wrong arguments to *fill_between*.

The proper parameters are as follows:

- *x* - x coordinates, in your case **index** values,
- *y1* - y coordinates of the first curve,
- *y2* - y coordinates of the secondt curve.

For readability, usually there is a need to pass also *color* parameter.

I performed such a test to draw just 2 lines (shortening column names)
and fill the space between them:

```
car_df[['inside', 'outside']].plot()
plt.fill_between(car_df.index, car_df.inside, car_df.outside,
    color=(0.8, 0.9, 0.5));
```

and got the followig picture:

[image]